# Using QUERY and IMPORTRANGE to get a value from Col8 when some of the rows in Col1 are subheadings

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, importrange

I just want to return the value in `Col8` corresponding to the row that has "Residential". I can only seem to get the value that is in the top row rather than the row corresponding with "Residential".

```
=query(Importrange("Key","Sheet Name!A:H"), "Select Col8 where Col1 = 'Residential'")
```

It just returns the top row value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you can try with **`contains`**:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "SheetName!A:H"), "select Col8 where Col1 contains 'Residential'")
```

- or with **`matches`**:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("ID", "SheetName!A:H"), "select Col8 where Col1 matches 'Residential'")
```

[image: 0]

**[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nu23JVQW7IXyEd1lDlgV5wCZEBkBHflql-JOXCvxfGg/edit#gid=0)**

Comment: I had tried both of those. I apologize for not giving more information as to solutions I had attempted. Thank you for providing input. Both of those still list only the value in the top row of column 8 (column H).

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: It will take a great deal of redacting as it has sensitive personal information. I will probably just have to have to redesign the census templates to include a simple count column that I can just reference directly. I do appreciate the responsiveness.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nu23JVQW7IXyEd1lDlgV5wCZEBkBHflql-JOXCvxfGg/edit#gid=0

Comment: @user213156 answer updated

Comment: Seriously thank you for the work you have put in to trying to help me. I actually gave really incomplete information. My second column (Col8) is actually coded by =VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(A:A,"\D+", "")) because Col1 has a bunch of names but has one row that is a subheading "Residential             (#)". I made Col8 contain only the # that is in parentheses. Then I was trying to reference that number that matched up with the row with "Residential" in it for aggregate census purposes.

Comment: OMG YOU SOLVED IT FOR ME WITH a SLIGHT change

Comment: =QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1Bg4iH4JQEJS2fmj5-3KpEPFj5uGd-w0IzjhwmjOWMmI", "LVRC Inpatient!A:H"), "select Col8 where Col1 contains 'Residential'",0)  Just changing = to contains fixed it. Wow thank you so much for doing it with so little information!!!!